# как сделать красивее код?

Tags: javascript

```
$(function () {

  $('#buttonTransform').on("click", function () {

    let valueOfInput = $('#GET-value').val();
    let valueOfInputToNumber = +valueOfInput;


    let valueToShow = '  sheep... ';

    for (let i = 0; i < valueOfInputToNumber; i++) {

        let output = [i + 1] + valueToShow;
        $('#place-for-value').append('<span>' + output + '</span>')

    }
  })
});
```

---

```
$(function () {

  $('#buttonTransform').on("click", wordShowing);

  function wordShowing() {

    let valueOfInput = $('#GET-value').val();

    let valueOfInputToNumber = +valueOfInput;

    let valueToShow = '  sheep... ';

    for (let i = 0; i < valueOfInputToNumber; i++) {

        let output = [i + 1] + valueToShow;
        $('#place-for-value').append('<span>' + output + '</span>')

    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Что такое "красивее"?

Comment: к примеру, функцию лучше писать отдельно или нет?

Comment: очевидно, если используется в нескольких местах, то одельно, иначе смысла особо нет. Разве что логическое разделение блока кода с навешиванием обработчиков, от самого кода этих обработчиков, имеет смысл когда кода и правда много.

Comment: Переписать его на Python

Answer (score 1):

Красивее - коротко и ясно, а не с кучей макарон.

```js
$('#buttonTransform').click(function () {
    
    let v = + $('#GET-value').val();
    let msg = '  sheep... ';
 
    let i = 0;
    while(++i <= v){
       $("span").text(i + msg ).appendTo("#place");    
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно в функциональном стиле сделать вот так:

```
$(function () {
  $('#buttonTransform').click(function () {
    $('#place-for-value').append(Array(+$('#GET-value').val()).fill().map(
      (x, i) => $("<span>").text(i+1 + '  sheep... ')
    ));
  });
});
```